How to use こと (verb nominalizer)
From what I understand, "こと", being a verb nominalizer, changes a VERB into a NOUN which roughly means "the act/experience of doing the VERB".
So:
"What do you like to eat?" -> "何を食べることが好きですか?"
(Or to put it more explicitly, "What do you like the act/experience of eating to be on?")
Is my understanding correct?
Next question, JLPT Sensei says that the "こと" has to be used with the plain (e.g. "食べる") and non-past form of a verb. And its examples are all with the present plain form of a verb.
But I also read from other sources, that "こと" can be used with the past (plain) form of a verb.
E.g.
"What have you enjoyed eating?" -> "何を食べたことが好きですか?"
(Or to put it more explicitly, "What did you like the act/experience of eating on?")
Which is correct?

When a resource gives you a rule like "use with non-past" they usually just mean "this is how to use it for the specific meaning were talking about right now." It rarely means that it's the only thing possible.

You can nominalize the past form of a verb. For example, 食べたこと is a valid phrase, and it means something like "the fact that (someone) ate (it)". This こと is still a nominalizer. You can use it like so:

日本の思い出は美味しいラーメンを食べたことです。
My memory in Japan is that I ate delicious ramen.
本物の天ぷらを食べたことはありますか。
Have you eaten real tempura?
(literally "Does the fact that you ate real tempura exist?")
トルコ料理では、何を食べたことがありますか？
Among Turkish dishes, what have you ever eaten?

(Unfortunately, "何を食べたことが好きですか" is not a natural sentence, and you should say "どの料理が良かったですか" or something instead.)
